# Image shows up in Design Preview, but not Application

Tags: apache-flex

I have some strange behavior.

My embedded images show up in the Flex Builder Design Preview, but are not displayed when the application is run. The images have relative paths (/assets/images/...), and the application is run on the server (wamp). I've appended the path to the compiled location (http://localhost/...) and tried to display a image in the browser, and the image exists, too.

I've compiled it via FlashDevelop, Flex Builder, and Ant. I've deleted and remade the bin/bin-debug/release/bin-release files to no avail.

Anyone run into this problem before? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) extension to debug the application requests, there you would be able to see the images path in the server.